# execute SIP call to deskphone .net

Tags: c#, voip

Need to build a simple c# app that takes command line args and then sends/makes a call to a deskphone which is SIP based so that the desktop phone dials the number

The application that does this is frSIP free app but this is for android, I need to make a simple desktop version. The format is (I think)

```
"sip:" + username + "@" + domain
```

I also want to replace the "callto" in skype to use this app instead.  How do I change the windows registry to override this callto function programatically?

I just want the desk phone to dial the number

Comment: Are you using Asterisk?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  This is exactly what we are currently trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\skype.callto\ there are a few different options to help you play with that.

You can probably replace the Skyp.exe value inside HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\skype.callto\shell\open\command to your own .exe file.  Just be sure to accept the same parameter input as Skype does when a link is clicked.